# How to get parameter by its index?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this array of objects:

```
const array = [
    {a: "aa", b: "bb" c: "cc", d: "dd"},
    {a2: "aaa", b2: "bbb"},
]
```

and I would like to console.log() parameters of first object in for loop but I don't know how to get paramater by its index so I can later replace it with 'i' variable in for loop. I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Slight [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here – the typical way to iterate over every key/value pair in an object doesn’t involve using an index (if you mean an integer).

Comment: you fall XY problem

Comment: so how can Iiterate through object?

Comment: There are many ways. Like `for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(array[0])) console.log(key, value);`